# Chef like version management in salt stack?

Tags: salt-stack, configuration-management

I really like the way that you can upload multiple versions of the same cookbook to Chef server.  And also you can specify the cookbook version in metadata file. e.g.

```
depends 'base-config', '= 1.2.1'
```

I like Salt.  However, I couldn't find any version management and requisite for Salt states/formula.  I am really surprised since I think it's a fundamental requirement for a configuration management.  Did I miss anything?  How do salt handles states/formula file versions?

Answer (score 2):

Some of this will be added in Nitrogen using [SPM](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/topics/spm/spm_formula.html#dependencies)

There are several more things that can be added to this, we are still working on getting an environment to setup uploading spms too, right now you would need to manage them yourself.

Instructions to build spms are here.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/topics/spm/spm_formula.html

Daniel